# Fullcalendar v5 rendering of all events is completed

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I could not find a way for an event call when all events are rendered.
Once all events are rendered then I need iterating through the each week of the month and do some calculations on it.

It looks as this option is available version 3 but not in version 5

Comment: You're correct, this was removed in v4.  The upgrade guide explains why: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3 says `eventAfterAllRender 
Removed. The concecpt of event rendering being fully complete is flawed (such as when events are revealed in a +more popup). You should operate on individual events instead, via eventPositioned or use some other callback.`. So you'd have to use the individual event functions, to keep a count of all events in each week in your own variable, and then use that for your calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventsSet

Please note that this callback is also called during the init phase (So its first call MAY NOT be the one you are waiting for)

In my case, I had to use a boolean to know if this callback has been triggered after an AJAX getEvents has been completed.